# Помогите пожалуйста с отступами в таблице

Tags: python, python-3.x, for, форматирование

Нужна именно та таблица, которая на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
n = int(input("Введите число, которое вам нужно:"))

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    for a in range(1, n + 1):
        print(i * a, " " * (5 - len(str(i * a))), end="\t")
    print('\t', end="\n")
```

Comment: нужно именно та таблица, которая на картинке

Comment: ну так посмотри внимательно на то, что у тебя получается и подумай, что нужно сделать/убрать/добавить, чтобы исправить. А потом уже думай как воплотить это в коде

Answer (score 0):

Я не совсем понял что надо сделать, но попробуйте так:

```
n = int(input("Введите число, которое вам нужно:"))

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    for a in range(1, n + 1):
        print(f'{i*a:>4}', end="") 
    print('\t', end="\n")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]